# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Lis<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AdventureCycle.Models.Product>'

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I was trying to query from AdventureWork2012 database using VS 2012, here is my code and I got an errors from this. I didn't know how to fix it, everyone can mention to me how to solve that. Thank you so much!

```
Model.Name = (from ob in db.Products join od in db.ProductSubcategories on ob.ProductSubcategoryID equals od.ProductSubcategoryID
                          where ob.Name.Contains("Bike")
                          select new { ob.Name}).ToList();
```

Comment: What type is `Model.Name`?

Comment: It's **List<Product>** CategoriesBikesViewModel.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting

```
select new { ob.Name}
```

which results in an anonymous type with a single `Name` property. Since it seems that the type of your `Model.Name` property is `List<Product>`, you might want to select the whole products, using

```
select ob
```

instead. That said, it's really weird to have a thing called `Name` and have it be a `List<Product>`. If it should be a list of names for the products, a better definition would be

```
 public List<string> ProductNames {get; set;}
```

and the correct query would be:

```
 Model.ProductNames = (from ob in db.Products join od in db.ProductSubcategories on ob.ProductSubcategoryID equals od.ProductSubcategoryID
                      where ob.Name.Contains("Bike")
                      select ob.Name).ToList();
```

Or, if you indeed need a single name, than it should be a string

```
 public string Name {get; set;}
```

and the correct query could be:

```
 Model.Name = (from ob in db.Products join od in db.ProductSubcategories on ob.ProductSubcategoryID equals od.ProductSubcategoryID
                      where ob.Name.Contains("Bike")
                      select ob.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```